# Problem with sed substition in multi-word regex

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Take this simple example:

```
echo "20150310 21:12:01.846338::: <?xml version="1.0"?><Haystack><Event " \
| sed 's/^\(.\{24\}\)::: \(<?xml.*><Haystack\|Foo\)>\(.*\)/\2 ts=\"\1\">\3/'
```

Will return:

```
<?xml version=1.0?><Haystack ts="20150310 21:12:01.846338"><Event
```

Essentially I want to take the first 24 chars of the line, insert them as a xml attribute of the root element and replace the rest of the xml.  This works.

But if I transpose the `Haystack\|Foo` to `Foo\|Haystack` it simply returns the original string, finding no match.  I actually have about 7 root elements to look for.

But the `\|` is supposed to be how you enter multiple words to match against such as in:

```
echo "foo" | sed 's/foo\|bar/nobar/'
```

So how do I get the () reference match to work the same way as above?

I'm using Fedora Linux, sed version 4.2.2.

Also, if someone can suggest a more efficient regex, I would be most grateful.  This is part of a much larger problem set with about 7 root XML expressions I'm looking for and need it to run as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression is telling `sed` to match either `<?xml.*><Haystack` ***or*** `Foo`. The Regex engine uses the capturing parenthesis to tell how far left or right to extend the `or` operator. (If you used a PCRE engine, then you could use non-capturing parenthesis.)

---

**Original, problematic code:**

```
echo "20150310 21:12:01.846338::: <?xml version="1.0"?><Haystack><Event " \
| sed 's/^\(.\{24\}\)::: \(<?xml.*><Haystack\|Foo\)>\(.*\)/\2 ts=\"\1\">\3/'
```

---

**Fixed code:**

```
echo "20150310 21:12:01.846338::: <?xml version="1.0"?><Haystack><Event " \
| sed 's/^\(.\{24\}\)::: \(<?xml.*>\)<\(Haystack\|Foo\)>\(.*\)/\2<\3 ts=\"\1\">\4/'
```